# Why is the boost server class throwing runtime error

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am getting a runtime error in the following code:

```
 boost::asio::io_context io_context;
 server server1(io_context, 1980);
 boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io_context));
```

Where the definition of the `server` class is:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        do_accept();
    }

private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
                }

                do_accept();
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};
```

The error is at the point:

```
server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE9D804F69 in Everest.exe: Microsoft C++
> exception: boost::wrapexceptboost::system::system_error at memory
> location 0x0000003AA613BDB0.

Comment: The error message shown is not a compiler error, but a runtime error (exception). Is this the actual problem you wish to solve, or is there a different compiler error?

Comment: @user673679 this is the actual problem i wish to solve

Comment: Please edit your question (to reflect that the code compiles fine, and also include at least the part of `main` that invokes `io_context.run();` because without that, no error would occur.

Comment: @sehe Thanks i will do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your code is missing a listen. On my Linux box this simply doesn't do anything, but perhaps on Win32 it throws an error due to invalid state of the `acceptor` when doing `async_accept`?

Here's a simple tester that does what is expected on linux:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    tcp::socket _socket;

    session(tcp::socket&& s) : _socket(std::move(s)) {
        std::cerr << "new session " << _socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
    }
    void start() {}
};

class server {
  public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
        : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        acceptor_.listen();
        do_accept();
    }

  private:
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
                std::cerr << "accept " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                if (!ec) {
                    std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
                    do_accept();
                }
            });
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    server                  server1(io_context, 1980);

    io_context.run();
}
```

Comment: Since [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70848303/revisions) introduces at least a second thread, consider using a strand per session: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b660f8f6b3a5597

Comment: Thanks i have updated my code and also understood the importance of strand for multi threads.